# App Engine & Spring Security: Concurrent sessions

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, session, spring-security

I'm implementing the authentication layer of my GAE + GWT app with Spring Security. My question is about concurrent sessions for one given user profile. I want to forbid any user from loggin twice with the same account, at the same time.

After some researches, I have found that I can do this in Spring Security using:

web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>     
</listener>
```

And in applicationContext.xml

```
<session-management>
<concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</session-management>
```

HttpSessionEventPublisher will receive an event whenever sessionDestroyed() is called in HttpSessionListener. But, as far as I know, App Engine never calls it.  There is an [issue about this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2117&q=sessionDestroyed&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log)

How should I implement session concurrency restriction with Spring Security and App Engine?

Comment: First you're going to have to define what 'at the same time' means in this context. HTTP is request based, not connection based; you can't tell when a user has stopped using your site - they simply stop sending requests.

Comment: You are right... when I said that, I intended to say "session time". Right now, I'm querying the _ah_SESSION entity with the last session Id used by a given user profile. If the session is not expired (_expires > now), I assume that the user profile is in use and I reject new connections. I have to try it in production.

Comment: That seems like undesirable behaviour - a user who closes their laptop (without explicitly logging out) and goes to their desktop computer to log in will be denied. Much better to automatically log out any other sessions, if you really must.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's going to work, GAE is a cloud solution and it populates various http sessions over the multi JVM by storing sessions in the data store and then it spreads them over other instances, it'll work fine in your development environment but will drop you down over the live server, so I don't it's possible to allow the single session solution over the GAE with spring security.

Comment: GAE keeps track of its session objects via cache and a collection in the datastore called _ah_SESSION. It's possible to query for expired sessions (_expires > now).

Comment: The only thing is that you should empty those data by yourself because sessionDestroyed() from HttpSessionListener is never called.